# Android Open File Associations

Tags: android, intentfilter

I can open custom file extensions when accessing browser links without problem. How can I associate my app with file extensions locally on my device?

Specifically I would like to:
1) Open a file that has been downloaded - I drag the Notifications screen from the top of my display which lists recent .xm files that have been downloaded. I would like to be able to tap on those and have my application open these files.

2) Likewise with other file explorer apps if possible.

Here are my intent filters. What am I missing?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xm" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>            
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xm" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

UPDATE: See below filters

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
            android:host="*" 
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.xm"
        />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:mimeType="application/mytype"
            android:host="*" 
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.xm"
        />
```

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of `<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>`, as nobody is going to know to put that MIME type on your file extension, particularly since [it's not the correct MIME type for `.xm` files, apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XM_%28file_format%29). Beyond that, please bear in mind that file extensions routinely get lost, particularly when files are served by `ContentProviders`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks - I only added that mimeType since somebody else claimed that fixed their similar problem to mine.. but still doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [post](http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/2013/01/26/registering_for_file_types_in_android/) has helped me solved the problem. I'm including the required intent filters above in the original question.